# Case insensitivity in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How to set case insensitivity for whole PostgreSQL database or even whole server / cluster?

UPD: For column values. I just migrated database from MS SQL and now looking how to get behaviour similar to what we had before for sorting, filtering and other stuff, in most painless way.

Comment: For column values? For object names?

Answer (score 2):

Unquoted [*identifiers*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) are case insensitive by default (and per SQL standard).

Other than that you *cannot* set "case insensitivity" in standard Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

**CITEXT is definitely the least painful route** (as per the suggestion from @Matthew Wood)

Use the following command to install the extension to the current database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;
```

This works great when running queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE serial_number = 'aB'
```

which will successfully match `ab`, `Ab`, `aB` or `AB`.

Where you *may* run in to trouble is if you are using parameterised SQL and letting a provider build the command for you. For example, using Npgsql (ADO.NET provider for .NET) with the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE serial_number = @serial_number;
```

actually sends this to the server:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE serial_number = ((E'aB')::text);
```

This is casting the value as "text" which means it will do a case sensitive lookup.
The way I managed to get round this was by modifying the Npgsql source code to add a "citext" type. Using this parameter type, the correct command would be issued:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE serial_number = ((E'aB')::citext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the CITEXT data type instead of VARCHAR/TEXT:

[CITEXT Data Type documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html)