# Ho do I read a postgresql citext field with npgsql 3.0.0?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Say I have a table called "exampletable" in postgresql with a 100 citext typed fields, let's call them "field1", "field2" etc... How do I read these fields using npgsql? Ideally I would like to use the following sql:

```
select * from exampletable
```

But when I execute the sql using npgsql 3.0.0 I get the following `NotSupportedException`:

> "The field field1 has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID 16466). You can retrieve it as a string by marking it as unknown, please see the FAQ..."

To overcome this I could manually cast all the fields to text in the sql query like so:

```
select field1::text, field2::text, ... field99::text, field100::text from exampletable
```

As you can see this is extremely verbose and cumbersome. Would I have to manually cast all fields to text in my query or is there some easier way to configure npgsql to allow citext types in the transfer? How would I handle other non-standard extension types in postgresql?

Any help will be appreciated.

**Bonus question:** I have tried finding the FAQ referenced in the exception message but I have failed to find anything. Do you know what page the message is referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, that type must have slipped through the cracks. I've [opened an issue for it](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/695) and will implement for 3.0.1.

In the meantime, you can either cast manually as you're down, or set your NpgsqlCommand's AllResultTypesAreUnknown to true. This will make Npgsql request all the resultset's columns in text, which you can then access. The FAQ is still in progress and not yet online, apologies for that as well.

Comment: Have created the FAQ section with info on this: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/faq.html

Comment: @ShayRojansky I have similar issue but it happens when citext field is used in the where statement with parameter of DbType string, then value and field is cast to ::text and expression becomes case-sensitive. Is there a way to fix this or some kind of workaround ?

Comment: I think I have the same issue like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20019795/467991

Comment: @khorvat try setting NpgsqlDbType.Citext instead of DbType.String on your parameter

Comment: Ok I'll see if that's possible as I'm using ORM tool and need to find a way to do override the default behavior . @ShayRojansky