# Npgsql 3.0.0 Fails to Parse Enumerated Types

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I have enumerated types in Postgres, defined as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE "SomeEnumType" AS ENUM (
    'Val1',
    'Val2'
);
```

I have the equivalent enum defined in C#:

```
public enum SomeEnumType {
    Val1,
    Val2
}
```

When I updated to Npgsql v3.0.0, deserializing a class with a property of this type fails.  For example, I have:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    Field1 "SomeEnumType" NOT NULL
);
```

And in code:

```
public class Foo {
    public SomeEnumType Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to deserialize my class, I get the error

> Error parsing column 0 (Field1=The field Field1 has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID 6965926). You can retrieve it as a string by marking it as unknown, please see the FAQ.)

I tried to add a type handler to Dapper, but that didn't resolve the exception.  I found [a related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921310/ho-do-i-read-a-postgresql-citext-field-with-npgsql-3-0-0) which points to a [FAQ page on the Npgsql site](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/faq.html).  However, the only answers on that page appear to be:

> 1) Change the query to explicitly cast unknown types to built-in types
>   2) Change all Npgsql queries to forgo the use of binary encoding

The first solution dramatically complicates my queries, as the real tables have many columns.  For example, using this solution changes all my queries from:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo
```

To:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Field1::TEXT, Column4 FROM Foo
```

This is clearly an unacceptable solution, since any number of changes (reordering columns, adding columns, dropping columns, changing column types, etc.) may require changing the query.  The second solution is more maintainable, but requires more data to be sent to/from the server, which will result in a performance impact.  Is there any other (read as: more maintainable) way to get Npgsql v3.0.0 to parse enumerated types?

Comment: Npgsql 3.0 includes native support for enums, unfortunately we haven't gotten around to documenting this yet. Am unfortunately not able to investigate your specific issue at the moment, but can you please take a look at our tests at https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/develop/test/Npgsql.Tests/Types/EnumTests.cs, especially GlobalRegistration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to register each enum prior to creating any connections.  In my case, this line was added to the static constructor of my data access layer class:

```
NpgsqlConnection.RegisterEnumGlobally<SomeEnumType>(
    typeof(SomeEnumType).Name);
```

If you are using case-insensitive naming in Postgres (e.g., didn't quote the Postgres data type), then you don't need to pass any parameters to the `RegisterEnumGlobally`, since the default value is the lowercase name of the C# type.

Comment: This is correct, although you shouldn't get a the cryptic error above if you don't do this. I'll investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

This response is for anyone experiencing this and the above solution doesn't work.

I had the similar issues. It turns out that for NpgsqlConnections you have to reload types if you were creating enums in migrations. I was using DpUp as my migrationstool and added `connection.ReloadTypes()` to the end of my migrator. More on this here https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html#creating-your-database-enum which I had only skimmed through and therefore ended up with hours of frustration.